# Remove Â from string using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

when i remove money characters then it work but i must require this chars

```
echo "Product Name :: ".$product_name = 'Â£5 off bookings at A1Travel';

echo "<br/>".$product_name = preg_replace('/(^([^a-zA-Z0-9$¢£€¥])*|([^a-zA-Z0-9$¢£€¥])*$)/', '', $product_name);
```

Output is :

```
‚Â£5 off bookings at A1Travel
```

Desired output:

```
£5 off bookings at A1Travel
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in `preg_replace`, can you clarify?

Comment: remove special characters. Allow only alpah numeric and money characters from string

Comment: You should look at fixing the actual character encoding issue rather than a hack like this.

Comment: These kind of string are coming from api so i don't have access on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added `^` and `$` which means it would only match at the beginning or end of string. So you need to remove them:

```
/(([^a-zA-Z0-9$¢£€¥])*|([^a-zA-Z0-9$¢£€¥])*)/
```

This means your regex could be simplified to:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9$¢£€¥]*/
```

Now let's improve it further. You never want to replace an *empty* string with nothing. So let's change the quantifier from `*` (zero or more times) to `+` (one or more times):

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9$¢£€¥]+/
```

You'll notice that this also removes spaces, so let's exclude it as well:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9$¢£€¥ ]+/
```

If you want to make it shorter, let's use the `i` modifier to match case insensitive and remove `A-Z`:

```
/[^a-z0-9$¢£€¥ ]+/i
```

After some debugging, it seems we need to handle utf/unicode problems. So let's add the `u` modifier like [nhahtdh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400768/nhahtdh) said:

```
/[^a-z0-9$¢£€¥ ]+/ui
```

To test this, you will also need to set the encoding for your HTML page. A simple example would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $product_name = 'Â£5 off bookings at A1Travel';
            echo 'Product Name :: ' . $product_name . '<br>';

            $product_name = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9$¢£€¥ ]+/ui', '', $product_name);

            echo $product_name . '<br>';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

<kbd>[**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iG6rT6/2)</kbd>

Comment: I have run at https://regex101.com/r/iQ5oT9/1 here it works but in my php page it is not working

Comment: All PHP regex should use `u` flag regardless, since non-UTF mode doesn't work on Unicode. Note that regex101 compiles from 16-bit library, while PHP uses 8-bit library.

Comment: @YatinMistry See edit. You will need to use the `u` modifier like @nhahtdh said. Also you need to set the encoding of your html page to utf-8.

Comment: @Hamza and nhahtdh thanks a lot it works now. Live server i have tried it without meta tag and it works.

Comment: @YatinMistry I would check [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) out. Maybe your live server is sending the page encoding along the headers...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$input = 'Â£5 off bookings at A1Travel';
$input = preg_replace('/[^\x00-\x7f£¢£€¥]+/u', '', $input);
//=> £5 off bookings at A1Travel
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gB6yW9/2)

Comment: Shouldn't `u` flag be used here?

Comment: Thanks @nhahtdh: Added `u` flag, I think regex101 demo didn't need it.

Comment: regex101 compiles from 16-bit PCRE library (UTF-16), while PHP uses the 8-bit library (UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
$str= 'Â£5 off bookings at A1Travel';
preg_replace('/[^\p{Latin}\d ]/u', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method also it will be much helpful

To remove â character from string

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

$price = "â‚¹ 310.00";

$price2 = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $price);

Result : 310.00
```

this helps to remove character like Remove Â from string using preg_replace

Thanks